# Stopping a while loop based on length of dictionary keys

Tags: python-3.x

Currently working on one question of my assignment and i face a bit of a setback. The question is meant to simulate a game of dice between players. Have solved majority of the question but hit an unexpected problem which i didn't simulate in the beginning.

Name of players are stored in a dictionary so the keys would be each player's name. There must be a minimum of 3 players and a maximum of 5.
Start by getting the names of 3 to 5 players. Players’ names must be unique. If user hits  before 3 players are recorded, an error message will be displayed. If there is a duplicate name, error message will be shown If user hit  when number of players are 3 or 4, game will start. If number of players is 5, game will start automatically without further prompt to enter player's name.

Been working with a While loop as error messages will have to be continuously displayed until input is correct of number of players hits minimum requirement.

```
players = {}
while True:
    name = input("Enter player's name, <Enter> to end: ")
    x = len(players.keys()) #count number of players
    if name in players.keys(): #error for when names exits
        print("Name already exists, try again.")
    if x < 3 and name == "": #for when user keys <Enter> when number players less than 3
        print(f"Minimum 3 players please, currently only {x} players!")
        continue
    elif x == 5: #when number players is 5
        break
    elif x >= 3 and x < 5 and name == "": #when number players is 3 or 4 and user hits <Enter>
        break
    else:
        players[name] = [[],2] #first list dice value, second is points
print(f"{x} players playing.")
return players
```

The recording of dictionary works fine, it only captures 5 names max. problem is after i successfully enter the fifth name, the While loop will run once more prompting another input and only then do the break condition for 5 players is satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to little bit reorder your code:

```
players = {}
while True:
    name = input("Enter player's name, <Enter> to end: ")

    if name in players.keys(): #error for when names exits
        print("Name already exists, try again.")
    else:
        players[name] = [[],2] #first list dice value, second is points

    x = len(players.keys())  # count number of players

    if x < 3 and name == "": #for when user keys <Enter> when number players less than 3
        print(f"Minimum 3 players please, currently only {x} players!")
        continue
    elif x == 5: #when number players is 5
        break


print(f"{x} players playing.")
print (players)
```

Comment: Oh, right that didn't cross my mind. thanks alot for the help!